# Using AWS, AngularJS project on port 80, does one use a non-port 80 for the WebAPI back end?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-ec2

I have a double project solution:  1) Angular front-end  2) WebAPI back end.
We are deploying to Amazon EC2 instance.  On that box I create one website on port 80 (stopping the default) for the Angular code.  I also create a second website on a non 80 port for the WebApi.  The solution doesn't work on the EC2 box at the moment only on my dev box with dev type settings.  Before I choose which remedy path I was wondering what is best practice.

Obviously, one puts the Angular on port 80 because it is html content but what about the api, does one put this on another port or does one use a dns subdomain and still port 80.  [At some point I'll need to do https as well so that is a factor, too many ports?]

Answer (score 1):

Both html and webapi's should be served by a single server ultimately.

This is because browers enforce [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) i.e same origin policy. If you receive html content from 'http://domainname:80/index.html', you cannot make ajax and http put/get queries to 'http://domainname:8080/api/feature' and so on.

That being said, you can have a front end listener like nginx or tomcat on port 80 and serve the angular app + all other static html directly on port 80. 
i.e you get your page at http://domainname:80/index.html and you can host all the api calls on a different port, but ask nginx to redirect those calls to a different port based on some rule you have to define , subdomain or anything which does not ask for index.html , make them redirect to your another server running on port 8080. Make sure to block public access to this port in your production environment so that nobody can directly call your api's

Comment: I'm reading about CORS, looks like it can be opened up these days by applying (in C# WebAPI code) EnableCorsAttribute("foo.com").  I take your point though and actually would rather like the forwarding feature you describe.  You say block public access to the api, I was wondering if was in fact close to impossible and perhaps this points to using port 80 because otherwise a open port scan would reveal the api more readily to an attacker.